# Run .each() on multiple element with the same index (i) rules

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach

I am developing a carousel and the logic works out well. But I noticed I am repeating the same code over and over in multiple jQuery each() method.

```
function Project(url, defaultColor, subColor){
  this.url = url;
  this.defaultColor = defaultColor;
  this.subColor = subColor;
}
var project1 = new Project("images/preview--1.png", "#9AB999", "#C5DEC4");
var project2 = new Project("images/preview--2.png", "#EC7F7A", "#FFB3AF");
var project3 = new Project("images/preview--3.png", "#E4475C", "#C45C6A");
var project4 = new Project("images/preview--4.png", "#00999E", "#35CFD4");
var project5 = new Project("images/preview--5.png", "#355D7D", "6DA2CC");
var project6 = new Project("images/preview--6.png", "#283338", "#638B9E");
var project7 = new Project("images/preview--7.png", "#CDE377", "#AAB67A");
var projects = [project1, project2, project3, project4, project5, project6, project7];


var imageSource = $('.image-wrapper picture source'),
content = $('.carousel__content'),
circle1 = $('.expand-1st'),
circle2 = $('.expand-2nd');
var scrollPosition = 0;


function loadNextProject(){
  scrollPosition = scrollPosition + 1;
  if(scrollPosition === projects.length){
    scrollPosition = 0;
  }

  imageSource.each(function(i, elem) {
    var num = i + scrollPosition;
    if(num >= projects.length){ num = i + scrollPosition - projects.length;}
    var x = projects[num];
    var url = x.url;

    $(this).attr('srcset', url);
  });
  content.each(function(i, elem){
    var num = i + scrollPosition;
    if(num >= projects.length){ num = i + scrollPosition - projects.length;}
    var x = projects[num];
    var backgroundColor = x.defaultColor;
    // console.log(x)

    $(this).css({'background' : '' + backgroundColor + ''});
  });
  circle1.children('circle').each(function(i, elem){
    var num = i + scrollPosition;
    if(num >= projects.length){ num = i + scrollPosition - projects.length;}
    var x = projects[num];
    var backgroundColor = x.defaultColor;
    // console.log(x)

    $(this).css({'fill' : '' + backgroundColor + ''});
  });

  console.log(scrollPosition)
}
```

I wonder if there is a way to loop through all the assigned element `imageSource`, `content`, `circle1` and use .each() with the same setting of the index `i`:

```
var num = i + scrollPosition;
    if(num >= projects.length){ num = i + scrollPosition - projects.length;}
    var x = projects[num];
```

The above codes was repeated in three each(). Can we just achieve the current with only one each()?

Comment: This may be a better fit - since you show working code that you want to improve - on [codereview.se], rather than here on SO.

Comment: Of course there's a way; it's called a `function`. Move the code to a function with the necessary parameters, then call the function instead.

Comment: I'm not sure, honestly, I'd be tempted to leave it as it is in order to provide context for the code; while we do request *minimal* - as in [mcve] - code, we need enough of the code to reproduce a described problem as well as enough to see and understand what it's doing in response to what event(s) or interactions.

Comment: I agree with @DavidThomas, this is an "how do I do X" type of question, not a code review request.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on a function with relevant parameter like below and it works. Just not sure if this is the best way. Any suggestion please kindly correct me :)

```
function loadAll(element){
    element.each(function(i){
      var num = i + scrollPosition;
      if(num >= projects.length){ num = i + scrollPosition - projects.length;}
      var x = projects[num];

      var url = x.url,
      backgroundColor = x.defaultColor;
      //
      // console.log(element)

      if(element == imageSource){
        $(this).attr('srcset', url);
      }else if(element == content){
        $(this).css({'background' : '' + backgroundColor + ''});
      }else if(element == circle1){
        $(this).css({'fill' : '' + backgroundColor + ''});
        console.log('run this')
      }else{
        return;
      }

    });
  }
  loadAll(imageSource);
  loadAll(content);
  loadAll(circle1);
```